# Updating Laravel Forge deployment repo from L4 to L5

Tags: git, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm upgrading from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5 and following the advise of [this tutorial](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-to-laravel-5) I have created a second repo containing the new Laravel 5 code.  I've now got everything ready to push it live, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to deploy it appropriately on Forge.

I would prefer not to uninstall my existing repo in Forge. Mainly because I don't want to risk messing up stored user files.

So, I am left wondering how to pull the L5 project repo into my original repo?

I've tried to make a pull request on bitbucket but I can't select an external repo.   I've tried a simple push, but I can't push to a branch on an external repo either.

As you can probably tell, I'm not a git master, really only use it for the basic functions at this point.

Comment: Is the new repo in a different branch or a new repo all together?

Comment: Can you SSH into the server? ( I currently use forge, I've been using it for a year or 2 now)

Comment: Are you trying to replace the current servers contents all together, or did you deploy another server to do this?

Comment: Only one server.  Frankly, the less that gets changed the better.

Comment: Maybe you could "Edit Deploy Script" to reflect the new git repo